# React Hooks : How to access custom attribute value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, custom-attributes, use-ref

I want to access custom attribute value using react hooks

Here is code

```
<div ref={cardNameRef} value="card-1" card-status="yes">Card 1</div>

<button onClick ={setData} className="btn btn-info">Select</button>
```

I want to access the `card-status value`.

Here is what I have tried

```
......
const cardNameRef = useRef();
 ....
  const setData = () => {
    let status = cardNameRef.current.getAttribute('cardStatus');
    console.log('status', status);
  }
```

Unfortunately, I get the following `status null`

What is wrong here?

Comment: Di you try `getAttribute('card-status')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get your custom attribute by below code.

```js
function CustomAttr() {
  const cardNameRef = useRef();
  const setData = () => {
    let status = cardNameRef.current.getAttribute("card-status");
    console.log("status", status);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={cardNameRef} value="card-1" card-status="yes">
        Card 1
      </div>

      <button onClick={setData} className="btn btn-info">
        Select
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule you need to use an attribute or prop name as is. If you call it `card-status`, use card-status. If you call it `cardStatus` then use cardStatus.
So this should work:

```
let status = cardNameRef.current.getAttribute('card-status');
```

In your case, `card-status` is not a standard div attribute anyway. I would suggest to change it to `data-status` or `data-cardStatus`.